# Default bibliography with bib-cite

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, emacs

I'm using Emacs 23 with `bib-cite-minor-mode`. However, this minor mode requires a `\bibliography{}` statement in the file. I have a master LaTeX file in which I have `\include` commands, so each section does not have a `\bibliography{}` command. How can I specify a default bibiography for `bib-cite-minor-mode`?

Specifically setting `bib-cite-aux-inputs` and `bib-cite-inputs` to the folder in which the .tex and .bib files are located did not solve this.

**Update:** I also use `RefTeX`, which I have since discovered includes the functionality which I was using `bib-cite-minor-mode` for: in `RefTeX`, `C-c &` opens the reference in the bibliography file. I was clicking on the reference using `bib-cite-minor-mode` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bib-cite-minor-mode` appears to be less sophisticated in searching out bib files than reftex. If you want to continue using `bib-cite-minor-mode`, but set it up to use RefTeX functions for actually finding the bibliography files, set `bib-cite-use-reftex-view-crossref` to a non-nil value. You can do this with `M-x customize-variable bib-cite-use-reftex-view-crossref` and following the prompts, or adding the following to your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq bib-cite-use-reftex-view-crossref t)
```

For me, the function `bib-display` from bib-cite-mode can't find my bibliography files unless I do this, so maybe it will fix your problem too.